# session to automatically appear in url

Tags: php, session, url-rewriting

I want my browser to automatically show sid attached to the url. I've changed some settings in php.ini file i.e 
`session.use_trans_sid = 1`
`session.use_only_cookies = 0`
`session.use_cookies = 1`

I've also disabled my browser cookies.

I have three PHP pages. First one is login and result.php and logout. i want to see sid e.g `result.php?sid=asdasd23hasjhd` when user click submit in login.php. or i have to hardcode it. in my form 
`<form action = result.php <?=SID?>` like this.
Because i have gone through such pages and its set php auto rewrite url with session id attached but i cant see it my pages.

Comment: Might I add how horrible of a mistake in terms of security to pass session ID like that?

Comment: i just needed an answer for my personal knownledge, since i am a beginner and its just came to my mind.

Comment: Your question aside, I would suggest not to go with this approach. Explain your situation, perhaps I can suggest an alternative to committing a digital suicide by forwarding a session ID via query string. :)

Comment: i was learning about session in php.net. and i read PHP is capable of transforming links transparently.the run-time option session.use_trans_sid are enabled, relative URIs will be changed to contain the session id automatically. so i just want to check that

Comment: If you just wanted to check out what you've read, then its okay. Play all you want to with the code but this approach shall not be used on a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the session id via a jquery script. `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default behaviour of the link and then you can add your session id.

You can get the current session id by the function `session_id();`

```
$sid=session_id();


<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.php" class="foo">link here</a>

$('.foo').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?sessionid='+<?php echo $sid ?>;
});
```

Comment: again bro i dont want to add this manually , is this possible that PHP will judge and attached and SID automatically if user has disabled cookies

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
session_start();
$sid=session_id();
?>
<form action="result.php" type="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value=<?php echo $sid;?> >
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

****Note :*** Check whether you have stated the session in the top of the page*

Comment: Thanks for your reply , But Rajesh i dont want to add this manually or with hidden html form field its just that i read in [link](http://hk.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)[/link] "session.use_trans_sid are enabled, relative URIs will be changed to contain the session id automatically." so thats why i want to implement that

Comment: @RickySaxena : The whole system doesn't work when a redirect is done somewhere. With every form and every link I call the same page, run it through a central file where I do stuff and then redirect accordingly. That effectively kills use_trans_sid. This means in that central file I must add the sid actually manually. Something like this:
`header("Location: " . $url . "index.php?sid=" . session_id());`